# Cannot get value to pass from Form SQL to Form Text Field

Tags: forms, ms-access-2013, calculated-field

I am trying to create a text field that will generate Label templates.  The information passes from the other form to this form.  1 of the two text boxes works.  The other text is formatted with an amalgamation of the SELECT statement from the form.

```
=[Model Name] & " " & [Size] & IIf([Manufacturer]="Apple",", Space Gray" & 
Chr(13),Chr(13)) & "IMEI: " & [IMEI] & Chr(13) & "Serial#: " & [Serial 
Number] & Chr(13) & [Vendor Name] & ": " & Format([Phone Number],"000-000- 
0000") & Chr(13) & "Tracker: " & [Tracker Number] & Chr(13) & [Employee 
Name] & " - " & [Project Name]
```

If I remove the & [Project Name], everything works fine.  As soon as you add it I get a #Type! response.  If I remove everything but [Project Name] I get a #Name? error. Note: [tblInventory].[Project Name] is a null value.  I'm trying to capture issues of blank fields at the moment.  However if it is not Null, it still gives me the #Type! or #Name? error  If I go into the form's SELECT statement, everything looks perfect. The code in the select statement for [Project Name] is:

```
Project Name: IIf(IsNull([tblInventory].[Project 
Name])=False,DLookUp('[Project]','[tblProjects]','[tblProjects].[ID]= ' & 
[tblInventory].[Project Name]),"None")
```

Works in the Select statement table, won't pass anything but errors to the form.  What am I missing. Been fiddling with this for 2 days...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Access often doesn't like if you use the same name for a calculated field as for an original table field. Try renaming this in the SQL: `myProjectName: IIf(...`, and use that name in the first expression.

Comment: Great thought! I've changed it to "Project", "TheName", "MyProject" and still get the same problem.